# Django filter() returning object instead of contents

Tags: python, django

Brand new to Django so excuse the newbie question. I cannot for the life of me get a Google search to return what I need.

First, I imported these using inspectdb.

Second, before providing the:

```
    def __unicode__(self):
       return u'%s %s' % (self.id, self.cuisine)
```

in the models, every database showed what looked like bound objects versus the actual data when looking in the admin. I assumed this was normal.

Now I'm trying to query the database and show the results. Just doing something simple, the code is:

```
def expand(request):
    userid = Userid.objects.filter(name__contains="Test")
    return render(request,'expand.html',{'userid':userid})
```

The return should just be Test 1, Test 2, but instead I get:

```
[<Userid: Userid object>, <Userid: Userid object>]
```

Tried userid, userid.name in the template and both return the object versus the contents.

Thanks, sorry for what I'm sure is a repeat question!

Model:

```
class Userid(models.Model):
    id = models.BigIntegerField(primary_key=True, db_column='ID') # Field name made lowercase.
    name = models.TextField()
    joindate = models.DateField(db_column='joinDate') # Field name made lowercase.
    visits = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    gender = models.TextField(blank=True)
    address = models.TextField()
    address2 = models.TextField(blank=True)
    addresscity = models.TextField(db_column='addressCity') # Field name made lowercase.
    addressstate = models.TextField(db_column='addressState') # Field name made lowercase.
    addresszip = models.IntegerField(db_column='addressZip') # Field name made lowercase.
    rating = models.IntegerField()
    lastvisit = models.DateField(null=True, db_column='lastVisit', blank=True) # Field name made lowercase.
    topcuisine1 = models.IntegerField(null=True, db_column='topCuisine1', blank=True) # Field name made lowercase.
    topcuisine2 = models.IntegerField(null=True, db_column='topCuisine2', blank=True) # Field name made lowercase.
    topcuisine3 = models.IntegerField(null=True, db_column='topCuisine3', blank=True) # Field name made lowercase.
    topcuisine4 = models.IntegerField(null=True, db_column='topCuisine4', blank=True) # Field name made lowercase.
    topcuisine5 = models.IntegerField(null=True, db_column='topCuisine5', blank=True) # Field name made lowercase.
    dealsparticipatedin = models.IntegerField(db_column='dealsParticipatedIn') # Field name made lowercase.
    privateoffersparticipatedin = models.IntegerField(db_column='privateOffersParticipatedIn') # Field name made lowercase.
    privateofferssent = models.IntegerField(db_column='privateOffersSent') # Field name made lowercase.
    toprestaurant1 = models.IntegerField(db_column='topRestaurant1') # Field name made lowercase.
    toprestaurant2 = models.IntegerField(db_column='topRestaurant2') # Field name made lowercase.
    toprestaurant3 = models.IntegerField(db_column='topRestaurant3') # Field name made lowercase.
    dob = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    tipsrating = models.IntegerField(null=True, db_column='tipsRating', blank=True) # Field name made lowercase.
    visitsweekday = models.IntegerField(null=True, db_column='visitsWeekDay', blank=True) # Field name made lowercase.
    visitsweekend = models.IntegerField(null=True, db_column='visitsWeekend', blank=True) # Field name made lowercase.
    reviewrating = models.IntegerField(null=True, db_column='reviewRating', blank=True) # Field name made lowercase.
    spendrating = models.IntegerField(null=True, db_column='spendRating', blank=True) # Field name made lowercase.
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'userID'
```

Template:

```
<p>{{ userid }}</p>
```

Comment: Post your model and template.

Comment: `qs = [<Userid: Userid object>, <Userid: Userid object>] for obj in qs: print obj.name` ??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to parse through the object elements individually.

Like this:

```
{% for user in userid %}
    {{user}}
{% endfor %}
```

--OR--

```
{% for user in userid %}
    {{user.name}}
{% endfor %}
```

The `__unicode__` attribute is applied only to individual objects, and not a queryset. Hence the issue.

**Make sure your `__unicode__` is on the `Userid` model.**

If you want to just display the name list, you can alternatively do

```
def expand(request):
    userid = Userid.objects.filter(name__contains="Test").values_list('name', flat=True)
    return render(request,'expand.html',{'userid':", ".join(list(userid))})
```

and your template would be just:

```
{{userid}}
```

Comment: This is just showing up as the same thing as before except now we have iterated through the list so instead of a dict it just says Userid object twice

Comment: yeah.. Looks like you do not have `__unicode__` on the `Userid` model. You need to put that in for the iteration to show the default value.

Comment: Dur thanks...so question on that, do I literally need to add __unicode__ and all 20 or so names??? That seems like a huge waste of development time. Of course I want to be able to access my database, why would Django format it so I literally cannot access my database unless I add all that?

Comment: @user1610719 Django doesn't do any such thing. This is basic OOP: the object has many attributes, all of which can be accessed via the normal dot notation: `user.name`, etc. But if you want to access the default string representation by just printing `user`, then you need to define a `__unicode__` method that defines that representation, otherwise you get the default `UserId object`. All this is well explained in the tutorial.

Comment: @user1610719 No, something like `def __unicode__(self): return self.name`.  That way treating the model as a string inside the template (like `{{ user }}`) will automatically print the model's name (as if you had just used `{{ user.name }}` in the template like in the first suggestion

Comment: Ok so now I got it, thanks guys! The problem was I needed to loop through it, and THEN I could access userid.name. Stupid newbie mistake. I did get the tutorial part which is why I was confused, as I thought I could access it without. Using the first suggestion in this post doesn't do what I want, but accessing the field in the for() does fix it! Sorry guys

Comment: Glad it helped.. Yeah. Daniel, and Izkata touch really good points. You are probably not defining `unicode` on the model, adding which would fix the issue.

Comment: Note, the `__unicode__` method needs to return a unicode object, not a string.

Answer (score 1):

In your `Userid` model, add the `__unicode__` method:

```
class Userid(models.Model):

   # all your fields
   class Meta:
       db_table = 'userID'

   def __unicode__(self):
       return unicode('{0} {1}'.format(self.name, self.id))
```